# AngularJS: How to wrap a synchronous function to make it asynchronous

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a synchronous function (that is an existing working code which means the author doesn't want me to change the code) and now on the task I am working on, the senior developer wants me to wait for this synchronous function to return a callback or wait for it to finish first before executing the next code. Is there a way to wrap an existing synchronous function to an asynchronous function?

```
StateChangeService.doChangeState('form', {id: '123123112313'})
```

This is inside the code itself

```
// They don't want to change this to an async function
doChangeState: function (state, options) {
    changeToState(state, options);
}
```

They don't want me to change anything on the StateChangeService so is there a way to get wrap this around an async method instead?

Comment: an asynchronous callback is a Promise, which can be returned from [`$q` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) with deferred object.

Comment: If you have to wait for the function to end, then it's not asynchronous, it's synchronous. So what exactly do you want ?

Comment: isn't it the other way round? "wait for it to finish first before executing the next code" this is a synchronous behaviour, no need to wrap in async function for that. Just execute your callback function after your function call if you need any callback

Comment: @Kaddath probably he just wants to have a `.then` on synchronous method. Wrapping it up with a promise (or $q) would do the trick.

Comment: @AdityaParab maybe, i kind of stopped making assumptions in SO, a problem well worded is a problem more easily solved.. promise is not a synonym of asynchronous by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use a promise for that.

```
asyncChangeState(state, options) {
  return Promise.resolve(doChangeState(state, options));
}
// To call it 
asyncChangeState(x, y).then(result => {...});
```

The callback in the `then` will only run once your function has been completed.

Comment: This is correct. However, while using AngularJS, I'd recommend using `$q.resolve` instead of `Promise.resolve` to maintain angular context.

Comment: **[q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)** is a wrapper for handling promises, while `Promise` is the pure version of promises. I wouldn't recommend using `q` for such simple behaviors. That adding unecessary code to something already very simple.

Comment: Thanks guys. Regardless this is a very helpful solution. I will just see if our senior would refer using q or Promise.